# Regular Expression Android For Number

Tags: java, android, regex

I've been here in a battle because of regular expressions ..

I'm getting something like that in Response `[14-23.0, 14-23, 23.320]`.I will Explain clearly in steps.

> a) The value which comes in response should be set to EditText.(Which i have Done)
>   b) The Value Which Comes in response Should not be Validated.
>   c) The Values which Comes other than response should be validated.

Below are the string which need not be validated.

> a)14-23.0
>   b)14-23
>   c)23.320

The Scenario Which need to be validated.

> a)14--23.0
>   b)1.4-23.0
>   C)14-2.3.0

Following Code i uses Which Doesn,t works.

```
public static String BondPricePatternValidation(String mString){

        String pattern = "(\\d+)-(\\d+).(\\d+)";

        // Create a Pattern object
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

        // Now create matcher object.
        Matcher m = r.matcher(mString);
        if (m.find( )) {
            System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0) );
            System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1) );
            System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(2) );
        } else {
            System.out.println("NO MATCH");
        }
        return pattern;

    }
```

Someone can help me in the regular expression to do this?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say it doesn't work? What are you expecting it to do? What is it doing instead?

Comment: I need to Validate the Following Strings[14--23.0, 1.4-23.0, 14-2.3.0]Which Doesn,t work by using following pattern. String pattern = "(\\d+)-(\\d+).(\\d+)";

Comment: So for input string `14--23.0` (for example), you want to know whether the string is "valid" or "invalid" according to a pattern?

Comment: your pattern will work. and for 14--23.0 your pattern will be     String pattern = "(\\d+)--(\\d+).(\\d+)";

Comment: if 14--23.0 should be invalid

Comment: Ignore my answers, neither is correct. Seems I underestimated the problem. I will keep investigating.

Comment: Got it, posting answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^(\\d+-)?(\\d+)\\.?\\d+$` should do the trick.

Let me know if it suits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question. So let me re-state your question as I understand it. You're looking for a regular expression that only allows either (1) a float-like number alone, or (2) what looks like a *range* between an integer-like number and either another integer or even a float-like number, strictly with one dash in between. Probably this isn't exactly it, but let me answer the question *this* way, and as you clarify I'll edit.

Let's start with the second alternative, the *rangE*. You probably don't want numbers like `0004`, so here's how you match a "regular looking" integer:

```
[1-9]\\d*
```

Then, you want exactly one dash, easy enough:

```
[1-9]\\d*-
```

Then, another number, except this one can be float-like, so let's use the quantifier `?`:

```
[1-9]\\d*-[1-9]\\d*(?:\\.\\d+)?
```

Now, to complete this, we just have to make the whole range part optional as well:

```
[1-9]\\d*(?:-[1-9]\\d*(?:\\.\\d+)?)?
```

And that should be it. By the way, as you can see, you need to escape your `.`s, as otherwise they stand for wildcards.

One last bit is concerning anchoring. You might simply add `^` and `$` on each end, so as not to permit other characters on each side:

```
^[1-9]\\d*(?:-[1-9]\\d*(?:\\.\\d+)?)?$
```

However if you intend to match this pattern within a larger block of text, you need to use a negative lookbehind assertion:

```
(?<![1-9])[1-9]\\d*(?:-[1-9]\\d*(?:\\.\\d+)?)?
```